# C++ установка пакетов в VS2017 с помощью Nuget

Tags: c++, nuget

Для учебного проекта установил пакет expat с помощью Nuget и подключил заголовочный файл

```
#include <expat.h>
```

но на любую попытку обратиться к функциям из этой библиотеки получаю ошибку LNK2019, например:

```
LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__XML_ParserCreate в функции _main
```

Подскажите, какие действия необходимо делать после того, как установил пакет? Или же его нужно устанавливать как-то по другому?

Comment: Убедитесь, что toolset пакета соответствует toolset у проекта. По идее, он должен быть v141. Убедитесь, что настройки, прописанные в property sheet пакета, корректные.

Comment: @VTT спасибо, именно в этом и была проблема. Не совпадали toolset.